# Sometimes pasting into gmail, it pastes text not an image from my clipboard

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail, copy-paste, clipboard

Gmail on browser lets you directly paste clipboard images these days - but I have had this bug a couple of times now on Mac where I take a screen grab but trying to paste, it pastes the text I copied previously.

I can paste the image into other applications so it definitely is in the clipboard, but something is getting screwed up. I have no idea what I did to fix it previously.

I have found that restarting Chrome seems to fix it, and that when the bug occurs I cannot paste clipboard images into SuperUser either. So I suspect it is a Chrome/MacOS issue not Gmail.

Comment: Do you have any programs modifying clipboard behavior? (Thinking about Dropbox capturing screenshots, clipboard managers, etc.) Have you tried in a new browser profile without any extensions?

Comment: I don't think so, and no I haven't - but I use this virtually every day and haven't installed extensions recently.

Comment: If restarting Chrome fixes it, I can only recommend updating it to the most recent version (I assume that this is the case already) and clearing all profile data. You may want to log into your Google account to enable syncing if you haven't done that yet – otherwise you'll lose all data, of course.

Comment: Try pasting the image into an image viewer, and *then* copy-and-paste that image into GMail. Or use another browser.